# Boolean switch refuses to operate as intended

Tags: bash

I have this code that I've been working on for hours now, I follow it manually and it SHOULD print:

> Missing Dependency: notacommand

Except it refuses to work properly and I cannot figure out why. What am I doing wrong?

```
__DEPENDENCIES=(touch clear sleep ln pacman sed mkdir wget notacommand)
for d in ${__DEPENDENCIES[@]}; do
  for i in $(echo ${PATH} | tr ":" " "); do
    if [ -e "${i}/${d}" ] ; then
      v=true
      break
    else
      v=false
    fi
  done
  if [ v = false ] ; then
    echo "Missing dependency: ${d}"
    exit 1
  fi
done
```

I apologize as I understand it's bad form to just post code asking for help, but I don't actually know what's wrong with my code in the first place so I'm not even sure what to ask or how to ask it.

Comment: [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net) loves posted code and automatically points out this problem.

Comment: Oh wow, that's cool. I've never heard of that site before, I will definitely start using that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're forgetting a dollar sign ;)

The line `if [ v = false ]` should read `if [ $v = false ]`

Although your script only gives me "Missing dependency: pacman", when I should get notacommand as well.

Comment: You have got to be kidding me... I've been at this for hours... 
And the script is meant for Arch Linux systems, should have specified I guess.

Comment: Ah, makes sense. What if you introduce `notacommand2` at the end of your dependencies, however? Does it print them both out?

Comment: Printing all missing dependencies was in my todo list, but I was trying to get it working first.

Comment: Gotcha, just making sure you knew about it `:)`

Answer (score 1):

Bash test doesn't support boolean, so v is a string variable. Use this:

```
if [ "$v" = "false" ]; then
    echo "Missing dependency: ${d}"
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Yeah. Funny things can happen if you use naked `true` or `false` in a script, since they are command names.

Answer (score 1):

Although your question has been answered, I have a couple of suggestions.

You are doing `$(echo ${PATH} | tr ":" " ")` inside a loop, which is a bit inefficient. And there's actually a nicer way to split your path. The script below puts the path elements into an array. The trick is to temporarily set the bash Internal Field Separator to `:`.

I've also modified your file existence check so that it uses an empty string for false and the found path element string for true. And I've used the modern `[[` style tests which are more user-friendly than the old `[` style, eg they are more forgiving over missing `"` quote marks; FWIW, the script below copes with crazy file names that contain unpleasant characters like spaces or quote marks. OTOH, `[[` is a bash-ism, not all shells support it.

```
#!/bin/bash

__DEPENDENCIES=(touch clear sleep ln pacman sed mkdir zorg wget notacommand)
IFS=':' paths=($PATH)
# for d in "${paths[@]}"; do echo "[$d]"; done

for d in "${__DEPENDENCIES[@]}"
do
    for i in "${paths[@]}"
    do
        v=''
        if [[ -e $i/$d ]]
            then v=$i; break
        fi
    done

    if [[ -z $v ]]
        then echo "Missing dependency: $d"
        else echo "$d is in $i"
    fi
done
```

Here's an alternate approach, which only finds a dependency if it is actually executable.

```
#!/bin/bash

__DEPENDENCIES=(touch clear sleep ln pacman sed mkdir zorg wget notacommand)

for f in "${__DEPENDENCIES[@]}"
do 
    echo -n "$f : "
    which "$f" || echo "NOT found!"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You are just reimplementing `command -v`.

```
__DEPENDENCIES=(touch clear sleep ln pacman sed mkdir wget notacommand)
for d in "${__DEPENDENCIES[@]}"; do
  if ! command -v "$d" > /dev/null; then
    echo "Missing dependency: ${d}"
    exit 1
  fi
done
```

Well, perhaps not. `command` will still find shell functions, aliases, etc, which you may want to ignore.

Comment: True enough. I assumed from the code in the question that FatalKeystroke just wants to check executable files, which is why my alternate version uses `which`. And of course, this could simply be a programming exercise...